# Why is every object in a locally presentable category small

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits, locally-presentable-categories

The definition I am working with is the following, a category $\mathcal{C}$ with all small colmits is called locally presentable if

- it has a *set* of small objects $S\subset Obj(\mathcal{C})$
- every other object is a small colimit of elements of $S$

Note: When I say category I mean a locally small category i.e. all Homs are proper sets. Here is how far I got, let $X\in Obj(\mathcal{C})$ we want to show that there is a cardinal $\kappa$ such that for every $\kappa$-filtered functor $F:I\to \mathcal{C}$ , we have $$Hom(X,colim_i F(i))\cong colim_i Hom(X, F(i))$$. Now $X=colim_j G(j)$ where $G:J\to \mathcal{C}$ and $G(j)\in S\  \forall i$ Therefore, by property of Hom, $$Hom(X,colim_i F(i))\cong lim_jHom(G(j), colim_i F(i))$$, and as each G(j) is small (we choose $\kappa$ which holds for all elements in S) $$lim_jHom(G(j), colim_i F(i))\cong lim_j colim_iHom(G(j), F(i))$$ Now for the required isomorphism, I need the limit and colimit to commute and I don't know how to do that.

Comment: You need to use the fact that $\kappa$-small limits preserve $\kappa$-filtered colimits.

Comment: @ZhenLin I am not able to prove that, can you write it as an answer?

Comment: It is a very well known fact. See e.g. [_Categories for the working mathematician_] for the special case of $\kappa = \aleph_0$.

Comment: Got it. Do you know if we can generalise this when the target category is not $Set$?

Comment: You can't, because it's not true in general.